# Djanjo Unique Constraint - Upload BUT Skip Duplicates

Tags: django, django-models, unique-constraint

I have a django unique constraint where im using the django admin site to import .csv files.  The constraint is working as expected but I would like to just skip over the duplicates and still add the valid records.  Is there a method to get this behavior?

```
def data_upload(request):
template = "data_upload.html"
data = ScanData.objects.all()
prompt = {
    'order': 'Order of the CSV should be CVE, CVSS, Risk, Host, Hostname, Project_Assigned, Component, Owner, Environment, Location, Notes, Protocol, Port, Name, Synopsis, Description, Solution, Plugin_Output',
    'scandata': data    
          }
if request.method == "GET":
    return render(request, template, prompt)
csv_file = request.FILES['file']
if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
    messages.error(request, 'THIS IS NOT A CSV FILE')
data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
next(io_string)
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=','):
    _, created = ScanData.objects.update_or_create(
    CVE=column[0],
    CVSS=column[1],
    Risk=column[2],
    Host=column[3],
    Hostname=column[4],
    Project_Assigned=column[5],
    Component=column[6],
    Owner=column[7],
    Environment =column[8],
    Location=column[9],
    Notes=column[10],
    Protocol=column[11],
    Port=column[12],
    Name=column[13],
    Synopsis=column[14],
    Description=column[15],
    Solution=column[16],
    Plugin_Output=column[17],
    )
  context = {}
  return render(request, template, context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work with [**`.bulk_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) and set the `ignore_conflicts=True` parameter. As the documentation says:

> On databases that support it (all but Oracle), setting the `ignore_conflicts` parameter to True tells the database to ignore failure to insert any rows that fail constraints such as duplicate unique values. Enabling this parameter disables setting the primary key on each model instance (if the database normally supports it).

You thus make a list of your model objects (but you do not save these yet), and then you use `.bulk_create(list_of_objects, ignore_conflicts=True)`. This thus looks like:

```
m1 = MyModel(field1=value11, field2=value12)
m2 = MyModel(field1=value21, field2=value22)
m3 = MyModel(field1=value31, field2=value32)
MyModel.objects.bulk_create(
    [m1, m2, m3],
    ignore_conflicts=True
)
```

Comment: Willem, I added some additional details to help explain my issue.  Would I add the bulk_create to my existing model?  I usually have to delete my database and cache to make model meta class changes.

Comment: @errMSG: you don't need t;o add anything, this is a `QuerySet`/`Manager` method...

Comment: Willem, im asking where do I put that code you posted?  I using a form to upload a .csv and want it to skip over the duplicates.

Comment: @errMSG: in the function where you process the csv file.

Comment: I have added my function above, where/how exactly would I add the .bulk_create(list_of_objects, ignore_conflicts=True) ?